# How to prevent fork in poa network?

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, forks

I discover that forks in poa network can happen!

I have 4 nodes (trusted nodes) I want to create a poa network with no forks,
is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Since since the only POA consensus mechanism on Geth uses clique which uses GHOST , the only option is use a consensus mechanism with instant finality.

I would look at Quorum (IBFT) or Pantheon (IBFT 2.0)

Comment: What did you mean ?