# Does uncle blocks in poa forks contains transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, forks

Since that forks can happen in poa networks (I asked how to prevent forks [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73647/how-to-prevent-fork-in-poa-network));
What does means ? is uncle blocks contains transactions or they are just empty blocks ?

Comment: Geth implementation of PoA doesn't have uncles.

Comment: how ? I can see uncle information in geth console. in addition sometime a transaction take a long time to be confirmed until another transaction comes (I use geth poa with period 0)

Comment: From the Clique spec https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225 _UNCLE_HASH: Always Keccak256(RLP([])) as uncles are meaningless outside of PoW_

Comment: In geth console there is : "Commit new mining work                   number=501 sealhash=b909a9…1b3aa1 uncles=2 txs=29 "

Comment: Do you see uncles in a block? Are you running geth/parity?

Comment: I am running geth, and I see in console that there is uncles, also sometimes I send a transaction and I still wait for response a long time

Comment: Are you sure it is a PoA and not a PoW network? Look at `eth.getBlock('latest')` from the geth's console, for a PoA network uncles should appear as an empty array.

Comment: yes uncles is an empty array, but can you please explain why transaction takes times to be mined ? (epoch period is 0)

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details of your PoA setup, number of validators, block time, etc. Are blocks being mined? How many transactions do you send? Are transaction mined or they just stay in the pending queue?